# Adjusting the angle of an svg isometric grid in HTML

Tags: html, css, typescript, svg, sass

I have found a codepen demo of an isometric grid that uses HTML SVG and SCSS that I want to use for my project, but the angle at which the tiles are skewed is 30°, and for my purposes I need 26.7° (as this is the angle at which tiles are made for the game Project Zomboid).

I have tried editing the angles, but this causes a staggered, stair effect on the grid tiles and they often overlap. This appears to be more of a math-based issue than anything else, but I have spent a few hours tinkering with the values to no avail. I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong, but it definitely seems that I either don't get the math, or I don't get svg construction in HTML.

This is what my attempts look like. Note the subtle staggering of each row on the left, as well as each tile's corner not aligning vertically (potentially due to overlap but it's hard to tell).

[image]

HTML:

```
<svg width="800" height="800"
     viewBox="0 0 800 800"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <rect id="basic" x="400" y="0" width="36" height="31.1736" transform="skewX(-30)" />
</defs>
<g class="grid-1">
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
</g>
<g class="grid-2">
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
</g>
<g class="grid-3">
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
</g>
<g class="grid-4">
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
</g>
<g class="grid-5">
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
</g>
<g class="grid-6">
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
</g>
<g class="grid-7">
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
</g>
<g class="grid-8">
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
</g>
<g class="grid-9">
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
</g>
<g class="grid-10">
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
  <use xlink:href="#basic"/>
</g>
  
</svg>
```

SCSS

```
$row: 10;
$col: 10;

@for $j from 0 through ($col){
  .grid-#{$j} use {
  /*  stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1;*/
    transition: fill .2s, transform .2s;
  }
  @for $i from 0 through ($row) {
    .grid-#{$j} use:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      fill: lighten(adjust-hue(#606EC3, 2deg*$i+5deg*$j),1%*$i);
      transform: rotate(30deg) translate(36px*($i - 1)-18px*$j, 31.1736px*($j - 1));
      
      &:hover {
        fill: lighten(adjust-hue(#606EC3, 2deg*$i+5deg*$j),1%*$i + 10%);
        transform: rotate(30deg) translate(36px*($i - 1)-19px*$j, 31.1736px*($j - 1) - 8px);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/Arcrueid/pen/PQVONB

Comment: I think you want a 3D transform but only Firefox supports those with SVG currently. Or you'd have to stop using a rect and use elements and calculate what path to render for each shape.

Comment: @RobertLongson In that case it makes more sense to stop using rects. I'll look into paths for svgs. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

**Why `31.1736px`?**

Because it is `36px * cos(30deg)`. Same as `18px = 36px * sin(30deg)`.

Whith that you can write better code. Remove the geometry attributes from `<rect id="basic" />` and set them in (S)CSS.

Unfortunately, (most) SCSS does not support trigonometric functions. Using the CSS trig functions also hits some problems, since at least some versions of SCSS won't support variables *inside* a CSS `calc()`.

*This is what I found from from testing. The [SASS playground](https://sass-lang.com/playground/#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) did not have problems, but on Codepen the result of the compilation did not substitute the variable names for their values.*

```
$row: 10;
$col: 10;
$skew: 26deg;
$base: 36px;
$baseX: $base * 0.4384; /* sin(26deg) */
$baseY: $base * 0.8988; /* cos(26deg) */

#basic {
  x: 400px;
  y: 0;
  width: $base;
  height: $baseY;
  transform: skewX(-1 * $skew);
}


@for $j from 0 through ($col){
  .grid-#{$j} use {
  /*  stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1;*/
    transition: fill .2s, transform .2s;
  }
  @for $i from 0 through ($row) {
    .grid-#{$j} use:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      fill: lighten(adjust-hue(#606EC3, 2deg*$i+5deg*$j),1%*$i);
      transform: rotate($skew) translate($base*($i - 1)-$baseX*$j, $baseY*($j - 1));
      
      &:hover {
        fill: lighten(adjust-hue(#606EC3, 2deg*$i+5deg*$j),1%*$i + 10%);
        transform: rotate($skew) translate($base*($i - 1)-($baseX + 1px)*$j, $baseY*($j - 1) - 8px);
      }
    }
  }
}
```